# How to Import TMY Data from NASA SSE Solar Database by location coordinates in Python?

Tags: python, pvlib, solar

I'm trying import TMY weather data from NASA SSE (Free) Solar Database via API call in my python App. I tried to explore wit PVLIB but the example codes that I found are maainly reading data from local library folder.

What I want to perform is that I will give location coordinates (Lat, lon) and Timezone as inputs and the program will fetch the TMY Data for that particular location from NASA SSE server.

Request your kind help on this..

Comment: I suppose you are talking about the NASA POWER dataset: https://power.larc.nasa.gov?

Comment: Yes Adam!! You are Right!!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not yet a function for retrieving NASA POWER data in pvlib, though it is on the to-do list. Hopefully, I'll be developing a function sometime next month. @pvrepy have you looked into using data from the NSRDB or PVGIS? pvlib has function for retrieving data from both.